# Thread Safety with MPI_Probe

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmpi

I am using `MPI_Probe` to send messages dynamically (where the receiver does not know the size of the message being sent). My code looks somewhat like this -

```
if (world_rank == 0) {
    int *buffer = ...
    int bufferSize = ...
    MPI_Send(buffer, buffersize, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else if (world_rank == 1) {
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Probe(0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    int count = -1;
    MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &count);
    int* buffer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    MPI_Recv(buffer, count, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

If I am running this code in multiple threads, is there a chance that `MPI_Probe` gets called in one thread and the `MPI_recv` gets called in another thread because of the scheduler interleaving the threads. In essence, is the above code thread-safe.

Comment: You're absolutely right that it's a race condition, and there was no way around it until MPI 3, with [MPI_Mprobe](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Mprobe.3.php) and possibly MRecv.  See for instance [Jeff Squyres' blog post](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/mpi-forum-roundup) .

Comment: @JonathanDursi, the link is broken. Jeff Squyres' blog post from Internet Archive https://web.archive.org/web/20151015111933/https://blogs.cisco.com/performance/mpi-forum-roundup . Unfortunately images (an important part of the post) are lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, MPI is not thread-safe by default. You'll have to check if your particular library has been compiled for thread safety and then initialize MPI using `MPI_Init_thread` instead of `MPI_Init`.

Supposing that your MPI instance is initialized for thread-safe routines, your code is still not thread safe due to the race-condition you already identified.

The pairing of `MPI_Probe` and `MPI_Recv` in a multi-threaded environment is not thread safe, this is a known problem in MPI-2: http://htor.inf.ethz.ch/publications/img/gregor-any_size-mpi3.pdf

There are at least two possible solutions. You can either use MPI-3 `MPI_Mprobe` and `MPI_MRecv`, or use a lock/mutex around the critical code. This could look as follows:

**MPI-2 solution** (using a mutex/lock):

```c
int number_amount;
if (world_rank == 0) {
    int *buffer = ...
    int bufferSize = ...
    MPI_Send(buffer, buffersize, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else if (world_rank == 1) {
    MPI_Status status;
    int count = -1;
    /* aquire mutex/lock */
    MPI_Probe(0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &count);
    int* buffer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    MPI_Recv(buffer, count, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    /* release mutex/lock */
}
```

**MPI-3 solution**:

```c
int number_amount;
if (world_rank == 0) {
    int *buffer = ...
    int bufferSize = ...
    MPI_Send(buffer, buffersize, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else if (world_rank == 1) {
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Message msg;
    int count = -1;
    MPI_Mprobe(0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &msg, &status);
    MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &count);
    int* buffer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    MPI_Mrecv(buffer, count, MPI_INT, &msg, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

Comment: Can two `MPI_Mprobe` (both taking ANY_TAG or the same tag) run simultaneously in these two threads and then interfere with each other?